# how to call constructor with arguments in REMIX (Solidity IDE ) from web3

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix

so i made a contract named "Voting" with Remix IDE and a constructor with arguments for this contract

i called the contract by doing this :

```
var Contractabi = web3.eth.contract(contract Abi from Remix)
 var vote = Contractabi.at(Smart contract @ in REMIX );
```

so until now everything works fine ! but now i need to deploy the smart with it constructor with arguments

i found few methods like this one :

```
var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(abiArray);

// deploy new contract
var contractInstance = MyContract.new([constructorParam1] [, constructorParam2], {data: '0x12345...', from: myAccount, gas: 1000000});
```

but it did not work for me !
How could i call My smart contract constructor with arguments in REMIX from my web3.eth.contract ! 
Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are using a newer version of web3. You can revert to the previous version 0.20.0 or use the new syntax below.

> When using version 1.0.x of web3 you need to pass in the Application
>   Binary Interface, i.e. abi. And use the `new` keyword

Docs https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#eth-contract

```
    Here is an example

    var contractABI = [{your contract abi}] 
    var subtestContract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI,{
         from: account1, 
         data: "your contract data", 
         gas: '4700000'
     })

    //arguments go inside deploy() using an array as follows
    subtestContract.deploy({arguments: ["hello"]})
```